# Angular proxy bypass intercepts all requests regardless of path

Tags: angular, proxy

I have an Angular app that uses a proxy when running with the "local" configuration. Here are the relevant bits of angular.json:

```
"my-app": {
    "projectType": "application",
    "schematics": {
        "@nrwl/angular:component": {
            "style": "scss"
        }
    },
    "root": "apps/my/app",
    "sourceRoot": "apps/my/app/src",
    "architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {...},
            "configurations": {
                "local": {
                    "assets": [
                        "apps/my/app/src/favicon.ico",
                        "apps/my/app/src/assets",
                        "apps/my/app/src/test-data"
                    ]
                },
                "production": {...}
            },
            "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
            "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {...},
            "configurations": {
                "local": {
                    "browserTarget": "my-app:build:local",
                    "proxyConfig": "apps/my/app/src/proxy.conf.js"
                },
                "production": {...}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the proxy:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    '/api': {
        'bypass': function (request, response, proxyOptions) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('/api/posts/')) {
                let filename = '/test-data/posts.json';
                console.log(`request redirected: ${request.method} ${request.url} -> ${filename}`);
                return filename;
            }

            console.warn(`request dropped: ${request.method} ${request.url}`)
            return false;
        }
    }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

It isn't clear to me what the key of the `PROXY_CONFIG` object is supposed to be. I expected that any request going to `http://localhost:4200/api/whatever` would be handled by the `bypass` function. What actually happens is *every* request going to localhost is handled as well, including the root page. Since the root request is dropped, nothing else loads.

I tried replacing the `/api` key with some random string and, sure enough, it still handles every request going to localhost.

Is this a bug, is the `/api` key meaningless, or have I got something wrong?

Comment: According to [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy), returning `false` issues 404 response, and returning `null` of `undefined` means "carry on with your proxy duty". Could this be the cause of your troubles?

Comment: @alx I understand that part. The question is why does the root page go through the bypass function when the key is "/api".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, alas, I don't have a better answer ATM. The fact it drops root request is rather weird, since according to [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) "Note that requests to root won't be proxied by default". My last guess is missing `target` key does some weird things, because (again, from docs) "you will still need to include a target key in your configuration here, otherwise webpack-dev-server won't pass it along to http-proxy-middleware" -- not very clear wording, but worth trying, I guess?